# force angular to re-enter controller on history back using Safari on Mac OS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have the following controller which is executed on page load and changes the value and state of a submit button. Full example can be seen [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pl7d7uCuA4tRbproT5PP?p=preview), and is based upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807471/prevent-multiple-form-submissions-using-angular-js-disable-form-button) question.

```
app.controller('FormSubmitCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.load = function($event) {
        $rootScope.event_target = $event.target;
        $scope.loading = true;
        $timeout(function() { $scope.loading = false; }, 5000);
      }
});

app.directive('disabler', function($compile, $rootScope) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        //var btnContents = $compile(elm.contents())(scope);
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(value) {
          if (value) {
             scope.initial_value = elm.attr('value');
             if (elm.attr('name') == $rootScope.event_target.name){
                 elm.attr('value', scope.$eval(attrs.disabler));
                 setTimeout(function(){
                        elm.attr('disabled',true);
                 }, 0);
             }
           } else {
             //elm.html('').append(btnContents);
              if (typeof $rootScope.event_target != "undefined"){
                  //server did not respond in timeline fashion .. inform user
                  if (elm.attr('name') == $rootScope.event_target.name){
                     elm.attr('value', scope.initial_value);
                     elm.attr('disabled',false);
                  }
              }
           }
         });
       }
     }
});
```

form.html

```
<input id="submit_item_button" name="form2_submit_btn1" type="submit" value="Go" class="btn" disabler="'Loading..'" ng-model="loading" ng-click="load($event)"/>
```

If the user successfully submits a form on the page, the user will be re-directed by the server to another page. If the user now immediately uses the history back button to re-enter the page, the controller is not entered anymore. This is an issue because the controller above changes the scope variable loading to true and if the user goes back he will still see the button showing the value "loading".

If the controller would be entered at history back the loading variable would be set to false and the button would show the initial, and correct value.

By accident I discovered that when I include (only include, no method call to it..!) the [jquery address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) ([paste bin code](http://pastebin.com/LHuhHKjS)) the controller is entered on history back, the loading variable is set to false and the submit buttons shows the correct value, not the loading.. value. Thus it seems as the address plugin triggers some event, which in turn triggers the angular controller. As I do not need the address plugin anymore I want to get rid of it, and especially I want to understand what is going on.

My question is now: How can I tell angular to re-enter a controller if the user enters the page through using the history back button in his browser!?

**Update:** I experience this issue only in Safari on OSX. Using Chrome the controller is also entered on history back, which is the expected behaviour. See the example setup by Thom Porter: http://so.thomporter.com/force-angular-to-re-enter-controller-on-history-back/

Comment: In Chrome, I click Go, let Wired.com load, hit back, and I see the Go button again, no the disabled Loading button.

Comment: Yes thats because jsfiddle. Seems as jsfiddle does a full reload of the page. I think I should setup a real "example" somewhere else to show what I mean.

Comment: I setup the code from the Plunker here: http://so.thomporter.com/force-angular-to-re-enter-controller-on-history-back/ but I am not seeing this issue at all.  Every time I hit back I end up with an enabled "Go" button, not the loading button. What browser are you experiencing this in and on what operating system?  I tried Chrome and IE on Windows 7.

Comment: You are right. In Chrome it works. Thanks for setting up the code! I was testing it with Safari on OSX. If you are running your example in Safari you will see the issue.

Comment: Looks like a caching issue... Browsers don't have a consistent caching behaviour... Maybe something like that helps: http://blog.55minutes.com/2011/10/how-to-defeat-the-browser-back-button-cache/... Or check if you get any events from angular's `$location` service...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Will check what I can change regarding the caching behavior or from getting some information from the $location service.

Comment: @ThomasKremmel I'm having the same problem. Did you find any solution yet?