# Asynchronous request and loading button with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

DOM manipulation within an Angular controller seems to be wrong. But this is not coming without a few headaches :)

I have a button, and on ng-click, it will perform an asynchronous request in the background. During the time of that asynchronous request I would like all the buttons (and maybe a few more elements on the page) to be disabled and the clicked button to have a loading icons playing.

What is the cleanest way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing / dealing with double button clicks in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130808/preventing-dealing-with-double-button-clicks-in-angular)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually do this with a variable on the $scope called loading. Whenever an asynch operation is happening, just set it to true. Then anything that's need to be disabled or otherwise affected can base it's state off of that.

Here's a dummy control:

```
function TestCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.loading = false;

    $scope.doASynch = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;
        $http.get("/url").success(function () {
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }
}
```

And here's a sample template.

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <a class="button" ng-disabled="loading" ng-click="doASynch()">
        <span ng-hide="loading">Click me!</span>
        <span ng-show="loading">Loading....</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I had the same idea but I was a bit concerned on how to make it looks really nice. I think this is definitely the base for it, however I would like to add an animation, maybe to make the other buttons to fade. If I want to apply jQuery effects, how could I do? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @JordyMeow you can post it as a next SO question, after you're accepting Mike's answer ;)

Comment: Alright, I will post the question later :) I am trying to create a directive by myself now but I'd like to know how guys would do it too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is exactly what you are looking for

[Loading animations with Asynchronous HTTP Requests in Angular JS](http://blog.jpamorgan.com/loading-animations-with-asynchronous-http-requests-in-angular-js?s=stackoverflow)

```
    var app = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.utils", "ui.router"]);

    app.factory('iTunesData', function($http) {
       return {
            doSearch: function(sQuery) {
                 //return the promise directly.
                 return $http.jsonp('http://itunes.apple.com/search', {
                        params: {
                            "callback": "JSON_CALLBACK",
                            "term": sQuery
                        }
                    });
            }
       }
    });

    app.controller('iTunesSearch', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, iTunesData) {
        $scope.search = function() {
          iTunesData2.doSearch($scope.searchTerm)
            .then(function(result) {
                  $scope.data = result.data;
                  $location.path($scope.searchTerm);
              });
        }
        $scope.searchTerm = $location.$$path.split("/")[1];
        if($scope.searchTerm!="") {
          $scope.search();
        }
    });
```