# Disable button while server processing in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, loading, server-side, disabled-control

I'm having problems disabling a button while processing a "long" request on the server.

Our application runs on a Java Spring/Tomcat backend and the front is using AngularJS.
Our users can click on a "Export" button to get a CSV file of some statistics. The problem is that this file is generated server-side by calling a URL like this:

```
<a ng-href="/exports?id={{the_id}}>Export</a>
```

and the response type is: `application/octet-stream`.

The request works fine but can be a bit slow. I'd like to **disable** the button while the file is generating, and **enable** it after the "Save File" window has appeared.
But I cannot intercept these events with a simple "synchrone" href.

I tried to process the request asynchronously with `$http.get()` but this time, I do not know how to serve the file the same way to the user when the process is done (the way Mega does it for example, for people who have already used it).

Thanks in advance !

PS: I know that, making the processing faster is another solution...but it is not really possible for now, and not the point :)

EDIT:
Problem solved thanks to Ed answer, with some modifications (I don't know if is a "good" way to do this, but actually it works for me exactly the way I want).

```
$scope.processExport = function(campaignId) {
    if (!$scope.exportProcessing) {
        $scope.exportProcessing = true;
        $http.get('my_generating_url').success(function(response) {
            $scope.exportProcessing = false;
            $window.location.href = 'url_to_retrieve_the_file_with_' + response.fileName;
        }).error(function() {
            $scope.exportProcessing = false;
        });
    }
}
```

And the corresponding HTML:

```
<button ng-click="processExport(the_id)" ng-disabled="exportProcessing">Export</button>
```

And `my_generating_url` is just returning the file name when it has been successfully generated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing / dealing with double button clicks in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130808/preventing-dealing-with-double-button-clicks-in-angular)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is quite difficult.

One approach is to modify the the way the server works: instead of accepting the request, then replying with the file itself when it is generated, the flow could be the following:

1. Receive `GET /exports?:id`
2. Generate the file locally (on the server) at an address like `public/tmp/somefile`
3. Once the file is generated, reply to the request with the path to the file (`www.server.com/tmp/somefile`)

Then, on the client you could do something like this:

```
function getExportedFile(id){

  $scope.exporting = true;

  $http.get('/exports?id=' + id)
  .then( function (response) {
    $scope.exporting = false;
    $location.path(response.data);
  })
  .catch( function (error) {
    // TODO: handle errors
  });

}
```

Which would work with:

```
<button ng-click    = "getExportedFile(fileId)"
        ng-disabled = "exporting">
  Download Exported File
</button>
```

Comment: Great idea ! I did not think to do this. I will try this as soon as possible and keep you informed, but I think this could work well.
I'm still wondering how Mega does to trigger the "Save file" dialog when the file has finished to download in the interface, maybe that way...

Comment: The iframe trick I posted above will trigger the save/run dialog. I have used this in a number of places to do exactly this. It doesn't change the current page location or contents.

Comment: I think MEGA uses the [filesystem API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html) which allows the website to write to a sandboxed section of your filesystem which it can do without user permission. After it's downloaded they just link to it, which then lets you save the file (very quickly) elsewhere.

Comment: @LeeWillis but it doesn't solve the problem of disabling/enabling the button which is the main point in the question. The approach I have posted shouldn't change the URL either - navigating to a file that can't be displayed in a browser should trigger the download's download dialog instead of a page load.

Comment: Ok, actually Ed was right, I encountered a problem when the file has been successfully generated, to trigger the download. And I solved it by using $window.location.href, instead of $location.path().

I will edit my post with the working solution.
Thanks everyone !

Comment: Good job - wasn't sure whether location path was quite right but glad you got the theory.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that can use $http by adding an iFrame to the DOM, then setting the src to the file url on the server. This will trigger the browsers default action for the file type:

```
$http.post({url to create the file})
    .success(function (data) {
        if ($('#iframe').length == 0) {
            var $iframe = $('<iframe id="iframe" style="display: none"></iframe>');
            $('body').append($iframe);
        }
        $('#iframe').attr('src', {{url to retrieve the file}})
    })
```

You will need to change the setting of the 'src' attribute to suit your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a promise along with your `$http` request and in the success function you should set a scope variable to true (meaning: loading finished). Initially, you should set this variable as false.

```
// in your controller
$scope.myData.loadComplete = '';

// below you call your service/factory to obtain your data and within the 
// success function you will change the variable to true
{
     // other code here

     $scope.myData.loadComplete = 'disabled';
}
```

Then you can have your button `disabled` during the time your `myData.loadComplete` scope variable is false.

```
<button disabled="{{myData.loadComplete}}">Disabled</button>
```

For your reference, see the Docs:

[ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that too, but how can you serve an `application/octet-stream` file then to the client with the dialog box ? that's all the question.