# Preventing multiple clicks in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

When I want to delete a record from my page I need to show confirmation message before deleting. For this I have used anchor and `ng-click='delete()'` for deleting such row. Here user can click on anchor multiple times. It is a serious problem because confirmation popup render multiple times. My example is a sample. In my project I have faced too many problems like that. I want to prevent multi click to extend `ng-click`.

Comment: can you show what have you tried so far? code or jsfiddle..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing / dealing with double button clicks in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130808/preventing-dealing-with-double-button-clicks-in-angular)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we override ngClick directive then we can protect multiple clicks.

```
app.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('ngClickDirective',['$delegate','$timeout', function ($delegate,$timeout) {
            var original = $delegate[0].compile;
                  var delay = 500;
            $delegate[0].compile = function (element, attrs, transclude) {

                var disabled = false;
                function onClick(evt) {
                    if (disabled) {
                        evt.preventDefault();
                        evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    } else {
                        disabled = true;
                        $timeout(function () { disabled = false; }, delay, false);
                    }
                }
                //   scope.$on('$destroy', function () { iElement.off('click', onClick); });
                element.on('click', onClick);

                return original(element, attrs, transclude);
            };
            return $delegate;
        }]);
    }]);
```

Comment: In my answer I have solved general ng-click multiple click problem(Protect multiclick at a time). Please see my answer. But in ng-repeat If I use ng-click then system accept multiple click. Please suggest me in this point.

Comment: This is a very inteligent solutions, i was looking for this, cause I'm developing an angular app with a tons of form and save time apllyimg this solution.

Answer (score 1):

for easier ng-click="your_function()"

`

```
your_function(){
if(this.allowClick){
            return false;
        }
this.allowClick = true;
// do your func her
//end function
this.allowClick = false;
}
```

`

hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a flag that denotes that the function has been and it is running / working state.  You can release the running / working state once the task is completed or cancelled.  Like so... (see `self.isWorking` or `vm.isWorkng` that is bound to `ng-disabled` directive on the link).  In the example below, user can try spam clicking the delete button and it will not pop up multiple confirmation box since once it's clicked the link will be in disabled state and will only be enabled again once the code releases it.  Good for form submission, etc. where you want to prevent spam clicking.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  
  angular.module('myApp',[]);
  
  angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('mySvc', mySvc);
  
  mySvc.$inject = ['$timeout', '$log'];
  function mySvc($timeout, $log) {
    var svc = {
      deleteSomething: deleteSomething
    };
    
    return svc;
    
    function deleteSomething() {
      return $timeout(function() {
        $log.info('Deleting something...');
        return true;
      }, 5000); //pretends the delete will take like 5 seconds
    }    
  }
  
  angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);
  
  myCtrl.$inject = ['$log', 'mySvc'];
  function myCtrl($log, mySvc) {
    var self = this;    
    self.isWorking = false;    
    self.delete = deleteFn;
    
    function deleteFn() {
      self.isWorking = true; //this should disable the link
      if (!confirm('Are you sure? OK to continue, Cancel to cancel')) {
        self.isWorking = false;
        return;
      }
      
      //confirmed...so delete..
      mySvc.deleteSomething()
        .then(function() {
          $log.info('Deleted!');
        })
        .finally(function() {
          self.isWorking = false;
        });
    }
  }  
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
<a href="#" ng-click="vm.delete()" ng-disabled="vm.isWorking">Delete!!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Jimmy Chandra@ But In a big project we have used many button or links. If we use such code in different pages then how would we deal such situation. i.e I need to control it centrally.

Comment: Unclear of what the issue is.  Is it repeated items each having a delete link that have to be confirmed?  If so, each item can have that state... independent of each other. `{ item:1, isEnabled: true }`.  Or make a directive that knows how to disable itself until its work is done (that will wrap the href or button or whatever HTML element you are using).  In this way, it is reusable.  Again, very unclear of what you are after.  If your SPA architecture is bunch of independent islands of controllers / views, perhaps message passing via `$rootScope.$broadcast` can help there.

Comment: See Kris' answer for that directive thing that I mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

my approach is to create a custom directive like this one

```
Module.directive("singleClick", ['$parse',
function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        compile: function ($element, attr) {
            var fn = $parse(attr.singleClick);
            return function(scope, element) {
                scope.running = false;

                element.on("click", function (event) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        if(!scope.running) {
                            var result = fn(scope, { $event: event });
                            if(!!result && result.finally !== undefined) {
                                scope.running = true;
                                element.addClass('state-waiting');
                                result.finally(function () {
                                    element.removeClass('state-waiting');
                                    scope.running = false;
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

it expects that called function returns promise.
It adds a `state-waiting` class on element and add a `running` variable to scope.

**EDIT:** Here is an example of usage https://jsfiddle.net/zsp7m155/

Comment: How to use it  in html ?

Comment: I added jsfiddle with example

Comment: @ Kris Jaklik, Is it  possible to remove $timeout from controller. Because I do not want to concern about it in controller section .

Comment: $timeout in controller is only used to emulate long running action, so you can see that it work. So sure you can remove it, but you have to remember that this directive expects that you'll return promise from action method, if not it will work just like normal ng-click