# Avoid double clicking when an onClick is pressing (Android)

Tags: android, onclick

I new in Android world.
I reviewed an old code, and I found that in any event on click, the `onClick` method contains check whether other click happened in last 0.5 seconds.
I'm wondering if it's necessary or it's over kill?

```
@Override public void onClick(View v) {
    if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 500){
        System.out.println("BUTTON CLICKED TWICE");
        return;
    }
    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: There's already an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130808/preventing-dealing-with-double-button-clicks-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this thing and it's really depends on the app logic - but generally what you can do it set the button state to disabled once clicked and restore enabled state once your logic completes or fails. You can also replace the button (once clicked) to a nice loader for friendlier user experience and once logic finished restore the button.