# How can I prevent a form button being clicked lots of times very fast

Tags: html, angular

How can I prevent a form button being clicked lots of times very fast?

I'm using html5 and angular2.

Currently they can just click it loads.

I need to only allow once if possible or atleast they have to wait 2 seconds before clicking it again.

Comment: I've no idea about angular2, but we used to use timeout to wait for some time make button enable once after it clicked in angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like that:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <div (click)="handleClick()">Click</div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.clicked = false;
  }

  handleClick() {
    if (!this.clicked) {
      this.clicked = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.clicked = false;
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
}
```

I think that you could also leverage Rx (it depends on the use case) and the `debounceTime` operator:

> Emits an item from the source Observable after a particular timespan has passed without the Observable omitting any other items.

This allows to trigger only the last event after an amount of time (here 500 milliseconds) when clicked a lot of time very fast:

```
this.ctrl.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).mergeMap(
  val => {
    return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users?d='+val);
  }).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data);
    }
  );
```

This sample shows such behavior when a user fills an input.

You can mix this with a `setTimeout` from enabling again the processing again an amount of time.

Rob Wormald made a proposal regarding such issues. See this link for more details:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4062

Answer (score 0):

What type of job the button does? is it a form submission or a refresh page button! The best solution would be to disable the button immediately after user clicks it, in case you are not navigation to a different page.

Refer this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18130876/5888071

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not specific to angular2, but I use this to debounce function calls:

```
function debounce(delay, fn, fnArgsArray){
    if(typeof fn.debouncing === 'undefined' || fn.debouncing == false){
        fn.debouncing = true;
        setTimeout(() => fn.debouncing = false, delay);
        fn.apply(this, fnArgsArray);
    }
}
```

example:

`<button onclick="debounce(2000, add, [2, 4]);">testen</button>`

```
function add(a, b){
    var sum = a + b;
    console.log(a + " + "+ b + " = " + sum);
}
```