# Enforce single click in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a client and calling my API  but it takes at least 2 seconds to respond so I want to that user cannot click the **REGISTER** twice.

I am incorporating this fiddle in my controller.

https://jsfiddle.net/zsp7m155/

But What happening is that first function takes 2 second to disable the button and after that it enables he button and send request to API. 
Am I doing something wrong here?

Code my my controller

**CONTROLLER.JS**

```
$scope.createClient = function() {


        ClientService.createClient($scope.theClient).then(function (aCreateClientResponse) {
            if(aCreateClientResponse[0] == $scope.RESPONSE_CODE.CM_SUCCESS) {                 
                alert('success');            
            } 
             else if(aCreateClientResponse[0] == $scope.RESPONSE_CODE.CM_DOMAINNAME_ERROR) {  
                 alert('Check your domain name');               
            } 
            else if(aCreateClientResponse[0] == $scope.RESPONSE_CODE.CM_INVALID_INPUT) {

                alert('Invalid request');               
            } 
            else {

                alert('Service is not available');        
            } 
        });          
 };
```

Code of my service

**SERVICE.JS**

```
 App.factory('ClientService', function($http,  API_URL, REQUEST_HEADER, RESPONSE_CODE) {

        createClient: function(aClient) {     

        var myCreateClientRequest = {
            "CreateClientRequest": {
                "Header": {
                    "CMMHeader": {
                        "Id": uuid2.newuuid()
                    }
                },
                "Client": {
                    "OrganizationName": aClient.Name,
                    "OrganizationDomain": aClient.Domain,
                },
            }
        };

        //API Call
        var promise = $http.post(API_URL.CREATE_CLIENT, myCreateClientRequest, REQUEST_HEADER).then(
        function(aCreateClientResponse) { //Success Callback

            return [aCreateClientResponse.data.CreateClientResponse.Result.ResponseCode,''];
        },
        function(aCreateClientResponse) { //Error Callback

            return [aCreateClientResponse.status,''];
        });

        return promise;
    },

              });
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="register-btn" name="register-btn" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="((Client.User.UserPassword !== Client.User.UserconfirmPassword) || CreateClientForm.domain.$invalid || CreateClientForm.username.$invalid || CreateClientForm.email.$invalid || CreateClientForm.password.$invalid || CreateClientForm.confirmpassword .$invalid || CreateClientForm.organizationname.$invalid )" single-click="createClient()">{{ running ? 'Please wait...' : 'Register' }}</button>
```

Comment: I am already using he to validate my checks
 <button id="register-btn" name="register-btn" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="((Client.User.UserPassword !== Client.User.UserconfirmPassword) || CreateClientForm.domain.$invalid || CreateClientForm.username.$invalid || CreateClientForm.email.$invalid || CreateClientForm.password.$invalid || CreateClientForm.confirmpassword .$invalid || CreateClientForm.organizationname.$invalid )" single-click="createClient()">{{ running ? 'Please wait...' : 'Register' }}</button>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing / dealing with double button clicks in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130808/preventing-dealing-with-double-button-clicks-in-angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options, the most simple is just to disable the button when you call your API and re-enable when it resolves. You could do it like this:

```
<button id="register-btn" name="register-btn" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="isRegistering" single-click="createClient()">{{ running ? 'Please wait...' : 'Register' }}</button>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.isRegistering = false;

$scope.createClient = function() {

    $scope.isRegistering = true;
    return $timeout(function() { 
        ClientService.createClient($scope.theClient).then(function (aCreateClientResponse) {
            $scope.isRegistering = false;
            if(aCreateClientResponse[0] == $scope.RESPONSE_CODE.CM_SUCCESS) {                 
                alert('success');            
            } 
             else if(aCreateClientResponse[0] == $scope.RESPONSE_CODE.CM_DOMAINNAME_ERROR) {  
                 alert('Check your domain name');               
            } 
            else if(aCreateClientResponse[0] == $scope.RESPONSE_CODE.CM_INVALID_INPUT) {

                alert('Invalid request');               
            } 
            else {

                alert('Service is not available');        
            } 
        }, function(){
            $scope.isRegistering = false;
        });          
    }, 1000);
 };
```

Comment: I am already using ng disable with some checks in it. Check updated answer <button id="register-btn" name="register-btn" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="((Client.User.UserPassword !== Client.User.UserconfirmPassword) || CreateClientForm.domain.$invalid || CreateClientForm.username.$invalid || CreateClientForm.email.$invalid || CreateClientForm.password.$invalid || CreateClientForm.confirmpassword .$invalid || CreateClientForm.organizationname.$invalid )" single-click="createClient()">{{ running ? 'Please wait...' : 'Register' }}</button>

Comment: how can incooperate checks with function?

Comment: You could add `|| isRegistering` to your existing ng-disabled and that should work. When just remember to set isRegistering-variable to true/false accordingly. You can use the controller in my answer for inspiration as a way to do it.

Comment: Also If I enter something wrong and after api call response. It will be still disable.

Comment: I've added`$scope.isRegistering = false;` to the error callback of `then`. That ought to return it to normal in case of an error.