# HttpResponseRedirect and CreateView: back button in browser?

Tags: django

Does HttpResponseRedirect prevent from going back on the browser and submit the form again?
CreateView uses HttpResponseRedirect right?
If yes, then I am confused about what I have.
By using this view and template, I noticed that I can go back on my browser and submit the form again and again... The value of the field being still there.

```
from .models import Person
class PersonCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Person
    fields = ['first_name']
    template_name = 'persons/create.html'
    success_url = '/'
```

And the template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The Django tutorial Part 4 says:

```
# Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
# with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
# user hits the Back button.
```

but I do not see this behavior in my case, what is different.

Comment: Yes, that's how browsers work.

Comment: Unfortunately, double submission is still not core of django. Try double-click the submit button on a "create" form with no unique value constraint. One solution is to generate a unique token for the form during GET,  check if ihasn't been submitted before and store it anywhere after save (e.g. user session).

Comment: oh ok because on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671335/prevent-multiple-form-submissions-in-django, it seems that HTTPRedirect and Django CSRF will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

"Does HttpResponseRedirect prevent from going back on the browser and submit the form again?"

-> this is one of its nice use.

Your problem is that you have forgotten `{% csrf_token %}` in your form template, and there's problably an error.

Moreover I dont know if `{{ form.as_p }}` displays the errors, try to make a loop:

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field }}
    {% if field.errors %}
        <ul>
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}
```