# how to create AbstractUser

Tags: python, django

For the account type i used AbstractUser to construct my model

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    pass
class Second(Profile)
    #fields here
class Third(Profile)
    #fields here
```

And the corresponding Forms follows

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

class SecondForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ('artist_name', 'music_genre', 'profile_image')
```

I don't know this is the right way for define model function

My question now is How to create a User include the `second model` or `Third model` field.?
I have the `HTML` page that user can select which account to create `USerType`..

```
def letsadduser(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        form_second = SecondForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and form_second.is_valid():
            User = get_user_model()
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)
            Second_user = Second()
            Second_user.artist_name = request.POST['artist_name']
            Second_user.music_genre = request.POST['music_genre']
            Second_user.profile_image = request.FILES['profile_image']

            new_user.save()
            Second_user.save()      

            #login(request, new_user)
            return render_to_response('welcome.html')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
        form_second = SecondForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/test.html', {'form_second': form_second, 'form':form})
```

The error **(1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'username'")** thrown right now .
but Its creating user, i think second form not working..
 How to solve this error ?

Comment: if you are using form_second, then why are you using `request.POST['artist_name']` ?

Comment: @ruddra then how to save the form_second values like artist_name or profile_image ... etc..?

Comment: Like this: `Second_user.artist_name= form_second.cleaned_data['artist_name']`

Comment: @ruddra Now also it's created the `user` but throws above error. why the user form submitted again when it's already created the User...

Comment: I don't know your Second() model's structure, secondly, you don't need to use `new_user.save()` because `User.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)` already creates the User, and third, what is artist_user.save() ?? I don't see any definition of the this.

Comment: Sry that's should be `Second.save() i updated my question now

Comment: try removing one by one error, first remove new_user.save(), then debug the form submission and check if its submitted twice. :)

Comment: i given like this #new_user.save(). Now also form submitted twice

Comment: If you are sure that is multiple submission, then check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671335/prevent-multiple-form-submissions-in-django

Comment: -1 ... oh ..i know the question is not equal to your standard .. i expect the ans back

Comment: Please edit your title. Otherwise you'll get many downvotes and/or the question closed.

Comment: check the answer I gave. you have multiple issues here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw these lines and immpediately noticed the issue you're having:

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    pass
class Second(Profile)
    #fields here
class Third(Profile)
    #fields here
```

When you create an user:

```
User = get_user_model()
new_user = User.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)
```

You're creating a user.

When you create the second user:

```
Second_user = Second()
Second_user.artist_name = request.POST['artist_name']
Second_user.music_genre = request.POST['music_genre']
Second_user.profile_image = request.FILES['profile_image']
Second_user.save()
```

You're not populating the `username` field. **Perhaps you ran this code at least twice** and an empty-user record exists in database.

However the big issue is not what you ask. The big issue is the following:

1. You call `create` on a User. a User entry is created.
2. You construct and call `save` on a Second instance. **Another User entry is created** and a Second entry is created.
3. You call, redundantly, `save` on the `create`d user. This call has no effect.

So you are creating **two** user entries. You must fix the model if you want to have one User having two profiles. Currently you have:

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Second(Profile)
    #fields here

class Third(Profile)
    #fields here
```

1. If you don't add fields to AbstractUser: Why don't you just use the default User? (just a convenience; not part of the fix).

   ```
   User = get_user_model()
   ```
2. You need to make **Profiles**, and not **Subclasses**, so the user may be of both profiles. This is a totally distinct OOP concept. So this issue is not about Django but about OOP.

   ```
   class Second(Model):
       user = ForeignKey(User, ...params...)
       ...fields...

   class Third(Model):
       user = ForeignKey(User, ...params...)
       ...fields...
   ```
3. You need to fix your call to instantiate users with Second profile:

   ```
   User = get_user_model()
   new_user = User.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)

   Second_user = Second()
   Second_user.user = new_user
   Second_user.artist_name = request.POST['artist_name']
   Second_user.music_genre = request.POST['music_genre']
   Second_user.profile_image = request.FILES['profile_image']
   Second_user.save()
   ```
4. For god's sake **make your view atomic/transactional**! You're adding multiple records.

Comment: i am gonna try your solution.. and i ll come back